# How fix problem with Arraylist when data not accepted in Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
class Client {
    public static void AddList(User user) {
    }

    static class User {
        public String name;
        public String age;
        public String mail;


        public User(String name, String age, String mail) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.mail = mail;
        }
    }


    static ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void AddList(String name, String age, String mail) {
        list.add(new User(name, age, mail));
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Give info plz");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        String age = scanner.nextLine();
        String mail = scanner.nextLine();

        Client.AddList(new Client.User(name,age,mail));

        Client.list.add("dqdqd");
        Client.list.add(1);

        for(Object s : Client.list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }


    }

}
```

This is a line when it doesn’t work for me, the program should take values and put them in an Arraylist, in general, the program should work like a database, take values and put them in an Arraylist, but this line does not work for me, please help.

```
public void AddList(String name, String age, String mail) {
        list.add(new User(name, age, mail));
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUqNs.png) as you can see in the screenshot, the data entered is simply lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you haven't implemented the `AddList(User user)` method. You've only implemented the `AddList(String name, String age, String mail)`

```
public static void AddList(User user) {
}
```

Should be something like

```
public static void AddList(User user) {
   list.add(user);
}
```

To print the object you will need to create a toString() method for your object.

```
static class User {
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String mail;

    public User(String name, String age, String mail) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + age + ", " + mail;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell me what can be done if the place value gives a link to this value

Comment: I don't understand the question.. Sorry. Do you want to add multiple values?

Comment: With JAVA you are always passing by value, so there won't be a link between your User objects when you add them to your list.

Comment: I get this less.Client$User@5cc7c2a6 instead of entered values

Comment: create a toString() method as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Answer (score 0):

You have two AddList(User) methods - one is a class method (i.e. static) and the other is an instance method.  You are calling the class method which has no body.  Since you never instantiate an instance of Client there is no purpose to the instance method.  Move the body from the instance method to the class method and remove the instance method.

```
class Client {
  static ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void AddList(User user) {
    list.add(new User(name, age, mail));
  }

  static class User {
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String mail;

    public User(String name, String age, String mail) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.mail = mail;
    }
  }
}
```